# Android TV: change the selected colour of ActionView in GuidedStepFragment(Leanback)

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

When i extends GuidedStepFragment the selection of action in action List is grey. How can i change it into blue?

```
public static class FirstStepFragment extends GuidedStepFragment {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public GuidanceStylist.Guidance onCreateGuidance(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String title = "Title";
        String breadcrumb = "Breadcrumb";
        String description = "Description";
        Drawable icon = getActivity().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_videocam_black_24dp);

        return new GuidanceStylist.Guidance(title, description, breadcrumb, icon);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateActions(@NonNull List actions, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        addAction(actions, ACTION_CONTINUE, "Continue", "Go to SecondStepFragment");
        addAction(actions, ACTION_BACK, "Cancel", "Go back");
    }


    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can override `onCreateActionsStylist` and return a `GuidedActionsStylist` where you provide a custom layout file in `onProvideLayout` with your own selector where the selected state is blue.

```java
    @Override
    public GuidedActionsStylist onCreateActionsStylist() {
        return new GuidedActionsStylist() {
            @Override
            public int onProvideLayoutId() {
                //return your custom layout here
                return super.onProvideLayoutId();
            }

            @Override
            public int onProvideItemLayoutId(int viewType) {
                return super.onProvideItemLayoutId(viewType);
            }

            @Override
            public int getItemViewType(GuidedAction action) {
                return super.getItemViewType(action);
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a new style with `Theme.Leanback.GuidedStep` as parent, and then change `guidedActionsSelectorDrawable` inside it with your prefered `drawable` like this:

```
<style name="MyGuidedStep" parent="Theme.Leanback.GuidedStep">
    <item name="guidedActionsSelectorDrawable">@drawable/guided_action</item>
</style>
```

You have to set this style as your activity's theme to apply changes to your `guidedStepFragment`. Note that you may use a `RippleDrawable`, since it's the default `SelectorDrawable` in the fragment.